I need Ozark replacement poles
I have a 6 persons Ozark tent model WT101310. I need to replace all poles. I have the part numbers but I can't find them. Does anyone know the size of the replacement poles, the parts number are:

fiberglass tent pole main     part no. HFP 11-622F
fiberglass fly pole           part no. HFP 6.3-183t


Have you tried contacting Ozark's customer support?

if you have the length and diameter of the poles, you should be able to replace them with generic parts

Appears to be a duplicate of https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/29678/good-tent-no-poles ? Between the two of you, can you build a complete, single question?

For your Ozark WT101310 tent model, you can usually find the replacement poles you need through many outdoor supply retailers or directly from Ozark customer service. Since you already have the part numbers (HFP 11-622F for the main pole and HFP 6.3-183t for the fly poles). Or you can look at specialty camping stores or online marketplaces like Amazon or eBay where similar replacement poles may be available.
