Good Tent; No Poles
I was given a 13' X 10' (~4m by ~3m) Pentagonal Dome Tent. It is in really good condition, but it has no tent pole. I looked around and getting new ones is not the problem; the problem is knowing how many and how long they should be. Any suggestions?

Do you mean the one by Ozark Trail? You need to [edit] that into the question. Also, the word is "poles".

Appears to be a duplicate of https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/29615/i-need-ozark-replacement-poles ? Between the two of you, can you build a complete question?

One could argue that the fabric without poles is not a good tent... The issue often is that most manufacturers don't keep tent poles for older models in stock, and you are left hoping that more generic poles will work well.

If you know what it's supposed to look like once set up, guessing the number of poles should be too hard.
As for the size, there are 2 options:

For bent poles, such as found in dome tents, there should be a clear path where the pole goes, which you should be able to measure
For straight poles, make a guess, try to replace it with something approximating (like a broom, a hiking pole, a stick, ...) until you get it right. Then order a generic assortment of pole parts (here it depends on the purpose of the tent, it can be steel, aluminium, carbon fiber). Exactly what sort of pole could be the subject of its own question, if you provide the length, how light you want it to be, and how big the tent is.


The problem with the "bent" poles is their length is pretty critical - too long and the (older) fabric may tear, too short and the tent may not stay up well (or long) in wind. The tension they apply is all part of the design.

true, it needs to be accurate. I'd recommend starting with something a little too long and trying to feel how much tension is needed before the final cut.
